# How to import a CSV file into a PostgresSQL database?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, csv

I have already created a table with 12 columns, and my CSV data have some column values.

For example, in the database I created a table named `book` with columns `b_name`, `author`, `age`, `address`, `year`, `publishers`, `no of sale`, `categories`, etc.
But my CSV file has the columns `b_name`, `year`, `publishers`, `no of sales`, `author`

Now I want to import the data into my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `COPY` statement.

```
COPY book(b_name, year, publishers, no of sales, author)
FROM 'CSV Location'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;
```

Use `HEADER` keyword if your CSV file contains Header.

As it is a CSV file we need to use `DELIMITER` Keyword as well as `CSV`.

Comment: No you don't need to specify `DELIMITER` unless the file is using one other the `,`. In other words the default delimiter is `,` for `CSV` format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`cursor.copy_from`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) function.

In `columns`, specify the table columns that correspond to the CSV file columns in the correct order. If there are any table columns that do not occur in the file, omit them, and those columns will be filled with NULL values.